# Can we find $\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n \le N} \mu(n)/\sqrt{n}$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Here $\mu(n)$ is möbius function.

Without assuming RH can we find if $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$  exists, and if yes, what it may be. Calculations hint it may have a very small finite value or may go to zero.

One approach I can think of is using partial sum which goes to zero as $N \to \infty$ :

$$  \sum_{n \le N} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} =  \sum_{n \le N} \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n \le N} \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}} - \int_1^N \frac{-1}{2t\sqrt{t}} \sum_{n \le t} \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt{n}} dt $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial summation gives

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt N} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt n} = \frac{M(N)}{N} + \frac{1}{\sqrt N} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} M(n) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)$$

where $ M(N) = \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n) $ is the Mertens function. We know from the prime number theorem that $ M(x) = o(x) $, which gives the asymptotic

$$ = \frac{o(N)}{N} + \frac{1}{\sqrt N} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} o(n^{-1/2}) = \frac{o(N)}{N} + N^{-1/2} o(\sqrt{N}) = o(1) \to 0 $$

No RH is needed for the result.

Comment: The result implies  $M(N)=o(N)$ thus the PNT.

Comment: @reuns I'm assuming that $ M(N) = o(N) $ in this answer already.

Comment: Still strange. To me it is $N^{-1/2}\sum_{n<N} o(n^{-1/2})=N^{-1/2}\sum_{n<N^{1/2}} O(n^{-1/2})+N^{-1/2}o(1)\sum_{n\in (N^{1/2},N)} O(n^{-1/2})$ $=N^{-1/2} O(N^{1/4})+N^{-1/2} o(1)O(N^{1/2})$

Comment: @reuns I just swapped the $ -1/2 $ and $ 1/2 $ by accident. Your argument is consistent with $ N^{-1/2} o(N^{1/2}) $.

Comment: @Shree $ n^{-1/2} - (n+1)^{-1/2} $ is $ O(n^{-3/2}) $.

Comment: I see, Got it now.